# how to hide dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can i add event such as hide to a dynamically created div ?

the php generates the below html code and then I append it to the page. after that I can click on delete li to remove the entire article div or hide it .

I tried this but did not work.

```
$( '.artical[id='+id+']' ).hide( "slow", function() {
    $('.artical[id='+id+']').remove();
});
?>
<div class="artical">
    <h1><?php echo  $obj['title']; ?></h1>
    <ul class="articalInfo">
        <li> February 12, 2014, 0</li>
        <li>Comments</li>
        <li>More</li>
        <li class="delete" name="<?php echo $id;?>">Delete</li>
        <li class="edit" name="<?php echo $id;?>">Edit</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
        <?php echo $obj['text']; 
            break;
        ?>
    </p>
</div>
<?php
    $( "body" ).delegate( "li", "click", function() {
        // send the id to removefunction to remove the element
        var r=confirm("Do you want to remove this artical?");
        if (r==true)
        {
            removeArticle($(this).attr('name'));
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).on( "click","li",function() {
    // send the id to removefunction to remove the element
    if (confirm("Do you want to remove this artical?")) {
        removeArticle($(this).attr('name'));
    }
});
```

Also your `code` you posted is wrong try this,

```
<div class="artical">
    <h1><?php echo  $obj['title']; ?></h1>
    <ul class="articalInfo">
        <li> February 12, 2014, 0</li>
        <li>Comments</li>
        <li>More</li>
        <li class="delete" name="<?php echo $id;?>">Delete</li>
        <li class="edit" name="<?php echo $id;?>">Edit</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
        <?php echo $obj['text']; 
            break;// don't use break if it has no loops and conditions
        ?>
    </p>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).on( "click","li",function() {
        // code for removing article after confirmation
        if (confirm("Do you want to remove this artical?")) {
            $('#'+$(this).attr('name')).hide( "slow", function() { // hiding the article
                $(this).remove(); // remove the article
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) JQuery Function

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function () {
       // send the id to removefunction to remove the element
        var r=confirm("Do you want to remove this artical?");
        if (r==true)
        {
        removeArticle($(this).attr('name'));
        }
 });
```

Comment: That would remove the <li class="delete"> element

Answer (score 0):

use jquery [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) like

```
$(document).on("click","li",function()
{
//your code
});
```

refer below link

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your javascript in  tags. Also note that your article does not contain an id, and lastly you'll need to process your javascript after the closing div tag. Note the following changes:

```
<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="article">
    <h1><?php echo  $obj['title']; ?></h1>

    <ul class="articleInfo">
        <li> February 12, 2014, 0</li>
        <li>Comments</li>
        <li>More</li>
        <li class="delete" name="<?php echo $id;?>">Delete</li>
        <li class="edit" name="<?php echo $id;?>">Edit</li>
    </ul>

    <p>
        <?php echo $obj['text']; ?>
    </p>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $( '.article .delete' ).click( function() {
            if (confirm("Do you want to remove this artical?")) {
                $(this).closest('.article').hide( "slow", function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure what action you want for the edit link, you've not provided any details on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code. This will give the desired result

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".delete").on("click",function(){ 
    $(this).closest(".artical").remove(); 
});     
}); </script>

<div class="artical">
    <h1><?php echo  $obj['title']; ?></h1>
    <ul class="articalInfo">
        <li> February 12, 2014, 0</li>
        <li>Comments</li>
        <li>More</li>
        <li class="delete" name="<?php echo $id;?>">Delete</li>
        <li class="edit" name="<?php echo $id;?>">Edit</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
        <?php echo $obj['text']; 

        ?>
    </p>
</div>
```